# Java String.format question for Time format

Tags: java, string, time-format, timeofday

I was working on a HackerRank question where I turn time in 12 hour format (hour:min:sec am/pm) into 24 hour format (hour:min:sec) (eg hh:mm:ss) . I got everything done, with 3 int variables for hour, min, sec respectively and I want to turn them into a string to return.
I use a string format like this

String str = String.format("%2d:%2d:%2d", hour, min, sec);  but  obviously does not work. I read the documentation on string formatter too but I try to get it work like what I was doing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing zero paddings.

Try

```java
String str = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);
```